# Able to create a var with protected constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, protected

I'm on a project where I have a Actor class, with methods and data members into it. It's like an abstract class, but I don't find useful to set it abstract (every methods are implemented).

```
public abstract class Acteur {
    /**
     * Empêchement d'instancier un acteur
     */
    protected Acteur() { }
}
```

The thing is that in a test, I can instantiate an actor :

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class ActeurTest {

    @Test
    public void testActeurConstructeur() {
        Acteur acteur = new Acteur();
    }
}
```

So my question is : how can that be possible ? I was wondering that only sub-classes can use/override a protected constructor ?

Thanks

Comment: Can be called from the same package. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-default-public-protected-and-private

Comment: But it's marked as abstract in the snippet above.

Comment: When I try out your code, I get an error saying: "Acteur' is abstract; cannot be instantiated". Make sure you're editing the right files, done a clean compile and so on. You should not be able to construct an abstract class like that. If you're confused about the visibility of things declared as `protected`, have a look at [this table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the question you are wondering that only sub-classes can
>   use/override a protected constructor.

`protected` can be accessed within same package.

```
Access Modifiers  In class     Same package    Anywhere but subclasses    Outside package & non relate
Private               Y             N                   N                          N
Default               Y             Y                   N                          N
Protected             Y             Y                   Y                          N
Public                Y             Y                   Y                          Y
```

[Java Access Modifiers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_access_modifiers.htm)